# XSLT - Separating parent and child nodes

Tags: xslt, parent-child

I just started 'playing' around with `XSLT` and I run into a problem that is not that easy to solve for me.

I got the following `HTML` code:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,...
    <ul>
        <li>The first entry</li>
        <li>The second entry</li>
        <li>The third entry</li>
    </ul>
    sed diam nonumy eirmod...
</p>
```

My result should look like:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,...sed diam nonumy eirmod...</p>
<p>The first entry</p>
<p>The second entry</p>
<p>The third entry</p>
```

I tried a solution where the `ul` template starts with a closing `p`-tag like

```
<xsl:template match="//p/ul">
    <xsl:for-each select="li">
        </p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

but this is not the correct XSLT-way. Another way is using this kind of hack

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</p>]]></xsl:text>
```

but I'm not sure if there is another, better solution for my problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit crude, but you could try this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[text()]">
  <xsl:variable name="text">
    <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:if test="normalize-space($text)">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/></p>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This matches ANY node with text, but tou could restrict that to `"p[text()] | li[text()]"` if you need to limit it.

It puts the text in a variable first just to make it easier to strip out whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your current template to match just `li`.

```
<xsl:template match="li">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

If you only wanted it to match `li` elements that are descendents of `p`, you could change the match to `p//li`.

In addition to this, you could have a template that matched `p` where you first select only `text()` nodes, to embed in a `p` tag, then select the other elements.

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()" />            
    </p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text()" />            
        </p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note I added a match on `text()` to strip out white-space.

Answer (score 0):

This is why "playing around" is not really the best way to learn a language. What you have probably been doing is reading some example code and building your own mental model of how it works - and that mental model is terribly wrong. The worst thing is, that once you've got it in your head it can be quite hard to relearn it. You need to get a good book on XSLT and read up on the underlying concepts.

The mental model you have created for yourself is that `<p>` in your stylesheet is an instruction to output a `<p>` start tag, while `</p>` is an instruction to output an end tag. Well, XSLT doesn't output tags, it writes nodes to a result tree, and writing an element node is an atomic operation, it can't be split into two operations each of which writes half a node. So, in the stylesheet, `<p>(content)</p>` is one instruction, which writes a `p` element to the result tree, and evaluates `(content)` to produce the content of that node. Which, incidentally, explains why the stylesheet has to be well-formed XML.

There are two ways of answering an SO question: "this is how to do it", and "this is where you went wrong". @TimC has given you a nice "how to do it" answer so I won't repeat that, but I thought you would also benefit from a "this is where you went wrong" answer.

Comment: I totally agree.I was aware that this is not the way XSLT works. But if you look around you'll often find these kind of answers. Your book is still on delivery. In a few days I'll got the opportunity to dive further into XSLT and the concepts behind.